# ASP.net Page_LoadComplete not firing on redirect

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect, page-lifecycle

I have a `MasterPage`, and a `Content` page.

Whenever a method is called on the content page that does a redirect, EG:

```
protected void DoLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var result = AttemptLogin();
    if (result.Success)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/home");
    }
    else
    {
        ... show error message
    }
}
```

It appears `Page_LoadComplete` is not fired.  The master page is set up as:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.LoadComplete += Page_LoadComplete;
}
void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Should a redirect be stopping this from firing?

Comment: You can try `Response.Redirect("~/home", false);`

Comment: HttpResponse.Redirect has 2 overloads. Just like VDWWD said, you need to pass false as second parameter to continue the request. The one you used just ends the request right after the call.